# Improve .NET/MSSQL select & update performance

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance

I'd like to increase performance of very simple select and update queries of .NET & MSSQL 2k8.
My queries always select or update a single row. The DB tables have indexes on the columns I query on.
My test .NET code looks like this:

```
      public static MyData GetMyData(int accountID, string symbol)
    {
            using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyData_Get", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@AccountID", SqlDbType.Int, accountID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@Symbol", SqlDbType.VarChar, symbol));

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var MyData = new MyData();
                    MyData.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
                    MyData.A = (int)reader["A"];
                    MyData.B = reader["B"].ToString();
                    MyData.C = (int)reader["C"];
                    MyData.D = Convert.ToDouble(reader["D"]);
                    MyData.E = Convert.ToDouble(reader["E"]);
                    MyData.F = Convert.ToDouble(reader["F"]);

                    return MyData;
                }
            }
    }
```

and the according stored procedure looks like this:

```
     PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyData_Get] 
 @AccountID int,
 @Symbol  varchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT p.ID, p.A, p.B, p.C, p.D, p.E, p.F FROM [MyData] AS p WHERE p.AccountID = @AccountID AND p.Symbol = @Symbol
END
```

What I'm seeing if I run GetMyData in a loop, querying MyData objects, I'm not exceeding about ~310 transactions/sec. I was hoping to achieve well over a 1000 transactions/sec.

On the SQL Server side, not really sure what I can improve for such a simple query.
ANTS profiler shows me that on the .NET side, as expected, the bottleneck is cnn.Open and cnn.ExecuteReader, however I have no idea how I could significantly improve my .NET code?

I've seen benchmarks though where people seem to easily achieve 10s of thousands transactions/sec.

Any advice on how I can significantly improve the performance for this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Tom

**EDIT:**

Per MrLink's recommendation, adding "TOP 1" to the SELECT query improved performance to about 585 transactions/sec from 310

**EDIT 2:**

Arash N suggested to have the select query "WITH(NOLOCK)" and that dramatically improved the performance! I'm now seeing around 2500 transactions/sec

**EDIT 3:**

Another slight optimization that I just did on the .NET side helped me to gain another 150 transactions/sec. Changing while(reader.Read()) to if(reader.Read()) surprisingly made quite a difference. On avg. I'm now seeing 2719 transactions/sec

Comment: There are many factors: you neglect to mention your hardware or hardware setup.

Comment: this code runs on several different systems. Benchmark on my test machine and in production are fairly close. Most of the machines are 8 core xeon machines with > 16GB RAM and SAS drives in RAID5

Comment: I'm sorry; are you seriously saying that you are disappointed with establishing a connection, running a stored procedure and processing the results takes 3ms?

Comment: @Stu: he shouldn't be establishing a connection every time (pooling), so I don't think 3ms is really all that quick to run a query that has been run quite recently (query already parsed and execution plan should be cached, heck there's probably a fair chance the data itself is in a hot cache) and returns very little data.

Comment: Yes - as long as the data in the SQL store is not invalidated, SQL should have it in memory and be very quick to look up due to the indexes. Connection doesn't have to be established every time due to connection pooling. With one of the distributed caches I'm running, I have no problem running > 100k queries/sec over 1gbps ethernet links (tcp). On my local machine where SQL connection is actually running over named pipes, I would not expect it to be slower by a factor of 300

Comment: Do you know what the latency is between your app servers and database machines? In my experience, the machine spends more time waiting for data to flow to and from the database than it spends actually processing the data. Rather than a `for` loop, try running your tasks in parallel (`Enumerable.Range(0,1000).AsParallel().ForAll(...)`). This will more accurately simulate the kind of performance you'll be getting with several multi-threaded instances on multiple machines.

Comment: negligible (microsecond range as far as production network goes) - for my local test environment, app and sql sit on same machine going over named pipes, so should be really fast

Comment: @Tom I suspect that the vital word in your >100k scenario is **distributed** - i.e. multiple threads and possibly even multiple machines accessing a single SQL server instance, not a single thread somehow executing a SQL query (over a network) in < 100th of a ms!

Comment: no, I said distributed because it's networked and replicates itself to several nodes (it's a custom built in memory cache - not SQL), however I can achieve 100k transactions/sec from a single thread & application instance

Comment: @Tom If you can execute 100k transactions sequentially in 1s, this (by definition) means that each transaction took (at most) 10us (that is **microseconds**) - typical ethernet latency is 350us, and so I must conclude that either the system that you claim manages this over Gigabit eithernet is far more remarkable than you realise, or what you are saying is simply not true!

Comment: @Tom Also, typical DRAM latency is around 60us, so even if no network access is involved what you are talking about is still all sorts of impossible on consumer grade hardware.

Comment: I don't know where you pull that number from but that's pretty far off. A minimum 64 byte frame on a 1Gbit link has a typical latency of 0.5 microseconds. A full frame has around 12 microsecond latency (12208 bits / 1000Mbps) + 0.5. Through request batching in 10ms intervals we're able to easily achieve those throughputs. Now, I understand that the SQL provider doesn't do any smart request batching but I'm also not expecting 100k transactions from it

Comment: @Kragen Also, on your DRAM comment ... not sure how old your machine is but on typical DDR3 RAM you're a couple orders of magnitude off (~10ns - NANO seconds that is - is the norm)

Comment: So? Even with your numbers what you are proposing is *still* impossible (10ms network latency + 10ms memory access time = 20ms), and even that's assuming that you always know **exactly** where to look **and** that's still ignoring the fact that SQL Server is not your faster-than-light system and it has to do things like look up your cached execution plan, look up indexes, deal with things like cache misses, data integrity, the laws of physics etc...

Comment: @Kragen - your numbers are completely off and your response is "So?" - seriously? You're consistently mixing up milliseconds, microseconds and nanonseconds and there is absolutely no physical limitation that would make the result I'm looking for impossible. Again, I have stated multiple times that I'm not looking for 100k transactions for SQL, I need only a little over 1k

Comment: If the goal is throughput then the way to achieve this is to bulk your requests up - in your case you would simply ask for many records at once and you should have no problem retrieving thousands of records per second, however the tradeoff that you are making is throughput at the expense of latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using WITH(NOLOCK) in your SELECT statement to increase the performance. This would select the row without locking it.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.A, p.B, p.C, p.D, p.E, p.F FROM [MyData] WITH(NOLOCK) AS p WHERE p.AccountID = @AccountID AND p.Symbol = @Symbol
```

Comment: whow, that helped a lot! achieving ~2500 transactions/sec now

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider.

First, your not closing the server connection. (cnn.Close();) Eventually, it will get closed by the garbage collector. But until that happens, your creating a brand new connection to the database every time rather than collecting one from the connection pool.

Second, Do you have an index set in Sql Server covering the AccountID and Symbol columns?

Third, While accountId being and int is nice and fast. The Symbol column being varchar(25) is always going to be much slower. Can you change this to an int flag?

Comment: Not closing the connection would explain it -- except that the OP is creating the connection object in a using statement, and Disposing the connection will close it.

Comment: 1) The "using" statement will call Dispose() which in turn calls Close() for SqlConnection 2) I wrote in my post that I have indexes on the columns that I select by. 3) No this has to stay varchar

Comment: 3) You say "indexes", is that one each or an index containing both? One each wont do you much good.

Comment: And while I remember... Add "TOP 1" to the select, it's stops SQL looking for more possible results once it's got the record.

Comment: ha, that helped, adding "TOP 1" improved transaction/s to 585! - As far as indexes, it's one index containing both

Comment: .Net uses connection pooling - you will only get a new connection to the database when all existing connections are in use regardless of whether or not you close your connections.

Comment: @MrLink TOP 1 probably wont make a difference either as SQL server should already knows roughly how many rows will be returned from the statistics.

Comment: @Kragen as I mentioned in my comment, TOP 1 almost doubled performance (from 310 transactions to 585)

Comment: @Keagan TOP x actually always make a difference. If you know the maximum results a query is going to return, adding a top command always makes a difference. 

This was one of the tricks I learned working on a 6bn record database 10 years ago. If you have a query returning 5000 records, adding TOP 10000 makes it's hugely faster.

What can I say, it's one SQL Servers meny strange querks.

PS, Known to be true on 2000 & 2005. Not tried it in 2008 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your database connections are actually pooling.  If you are seeing a bottleneck in cnn.Open, there would seem to be a good chance they are not getting pooled.

Answer (score 1):

> I was hoping to achieve well over a 1000 transactions/sec [when running `GetMyData` in a loop]

What you are asking for is for `GetMyData` to run in less than 1ms - this is just **pointless** optimisation!  At the bare minimum this method involves a round trip to the database server (possibly involving network access) - you wouldn't be able to make this method much faster if your query was `SELECT 1`.

If you have a genuine requirement to make more requests per second then the answer is either to use multiple threads or to buy a faster PC.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code - I'm not sure where you have seen people managing 10,000+ transactions per second, but I'm sure this must have involved multiple concurrent clients accessing the same database server rather than a single thread managing to execute queries in less than a 10th of a ms!

Comment: I completely disagree - I work in the financial services industry and have multiple software components in our infrastructure that easily achieve 100k roundtrip transactions/sec from a single thread * & instance. I realize that this is probably unrealistic with SQL but 1ms for a simple transaction, that should happen completely in memory over named pipes or shared memory should not at all be unrealistic nor pointless. MrLink's tip with SELECT TOP 1 in the query already almost doubled the transactions performance to 585 transations/sec

Comment: +1 for idea about timing this and seeing transaction speeds with SELECT 1. @tom - how big a difference would that make? Just curious because it would tell where the bottleneck lies - with the code or the database query & round-trip

Comment: nice idea, just tried that and a stored proc with SELECT 1 from my .NET code achieves 11421 transactions/sec. However, not sure if you've seen my edits, but having the SELECT WITH(NOLOCK) helped the biggest so far and I'm seeing over 2500 transactions/sec which I'm pretty happy with!

Answer (score 0):

Is your method called frequently? Could you batch your requests so you can open your connection, create your parameters, get the result and reuse them for several queries before closing the whole thing up again?

Comment: called very frequently but in irregular intervals and I can't delay/batch queries (financial trading application - timeliness is critical)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not frequently invalidated (updated) I would implement a cache layer. This is one of the most effective ways (if used correctly) to gain performance.

Comment: there are multiple servers reading/writing from the database at very high frequent intervals - I actually do a have a caching layer in place for the reads but it has to be invalidated quite frequently. The writes I can't batch or delay, they have to be commited to the DB asap.

Answer (score 0):

You could use output parameters instead of a select since there's always a single row.

You could also create the SqlCommand ahead of time and re-use it.  If you are executing a lot of queries in a single thread you can keep executing it on the same connection.  If not, you could create a pool of them or do cmdTemplate.Clone() and set the Connection.

Comment: just tried this in 2 steps: 1) leaving connection open and reusing SqlCommand -> I'm now getting 317 vs 310 transactions/sec. I guess the connection pooling is pretty efficient and SqlCommand has low overhead 2) Output parameters vs SELECT -> did not seem to make a difference, still around 317 transactions/sec

Comment: .Net already uses connection pooling - attempting to re-use the same SqlCommand / SqlConnection will at best save you the overhead of creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-using the Command and [Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.prepare.aspx)'ing it first.

I can't say that it will definitely help, but it seems worth a try.

Comment: Just tried this per recommendation from Jason Goemaat. Unfortunately it barely helped (see my comment under his post)

Comment: hmm .. then I would say at this point, on the .Net side at least, there is nothing left to help.

Comment: As the query is the same each time the execution plan will already be cached and so preparing it won't really make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In no particular order...

- Have you (or your DBAs) examined the execution plan your stored procedure is getting? Has SQL Server cached a bogus execution plan (either due to oddball parameters or old stats).
- How often are statistics updated on the database?
- Do you use temp tables in your stored procedure? If so, are they create upfront. If not, you'll be doing a lot of recompiles as creating a temp table invalidates the execution plan.
- Are you using connection pooling? Opening/Closing a SQL server connection is an expensive operation.
- Is your table clustered on accountID and Symbol?

Finally...

- Is there a reason you're hitting this table by account and symbol rather than, say, just retrieving  all the data for an entire account in one fell swoop?

Comment: 1) yes, but don't see an issue with the execution plan 2) weekly 3) no 4) yes 5) no, the clustered index is the primary key, symbol/accountID index are not clustered 6) yes there is as most of the time I will only need that exact record and another server could invalidate another record for the same accountID just a couple ms later